# Does Vedanta accept the validity of Jyotish?

Tags: vedanta, astrology, navagraha

Gita 10.37 talks about Usanas or Acharya Shukra. Is Shukra to be considered a graha or a kavi in the Gita context? Some one told me that the implication of the Gita identifying Shukra only as Kavi and not as graha is that Vedanta does not accept the validity of Jyotish. Hence I asked the above question.

Comment: This [may](https://tamilandvedas.com/2014/10/20/oldest-poet-usanas-kavi/) useful.

Comment: sorry for my lack of knowledge in this topic, but I am confused with the Q's title and the body! I could not relate what you are asking in the body of question to Q's title. i get the Q you are asking in the body, but not the title of the Q :(

Comment: The title of your question is broader than the actual question (that is asked in the body of question)!

Comment: Gita verse 10.37 is not speaking about astrology, but that emphatically does not mean that Vedanta rejects astrology.  The two have nothing to do with each other.  And in fact numerous Acharyas of the Vedanta school have written approvingly of Vedic astrology.

Comment: I was told by some one that the implication of the Gita referring to Shukra only as Kavi and not as graha is that Vedanta has nothing to do with Jyotish. I am not sure if his claim is true. Hence my question.

Comment: *Jyotisha* is one of the eight *vedanga*. I don't think any *vedanta* will reject *jyotisha*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does Vedanta accept the validity of Jyotish?

Of course, it does, for it being a Vedāṅga. Moreover, the famous Viśiśṭa Advaita Ācārya (a Vedantin) had written an astrological treatise that goes by the name of [Bhāvartha Ratnākara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhavartha_Ratnakara). — also an instance of holistic erudition of ancient philosophers.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the full [BG 10.37](http://asitis.com/10/37.html) for quick analysis:

> vrsninam vasudevo 'smi pandavanam dhananjayah muninam apy aham vyasah
>   **kavinam usana kavih**

Let us first try to understand what is mean by `kavih`. I guess most of us use the word ‘Kavi’ for a poet. But it seems it has more [deep meaning](http://asitis.com/10/37.html) :

> Kavis are those who are capable of thinking thoroughly on any subject
>   matter.

And "**thinking**" usually associate with living beings. Hence, this hints us that in BG 10.37, a person is referred as a Kavi (one who can think thoroughly on any subject) and not Graha.

The vibhuti [Usana](http://asitis.com/10/37.html) mentioned in BG 10.37 have qualities such as intelligence, far-seeing

> Uśanā was the spiritual master of the demons; he was extremely
>   intelligent, far-seeing, political and spiritual in every way.

After checking [4 different translation and analysis](http://www.bhagavad-gita.org/Gita/verse-10-35.html), it further reinforces that, in BG 10.37,Shukra to be considered as kavi.

Hence, at least to me, it seems that in BG 10.37, **Shukra to be considered as kavi.**